Barcode Generating Error missing 1 required positional argument
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date


def generate_random_n_digits(n):
    """Generates a random integer with n digits."""
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

def generate_barcode(material_num, random_digits):
    """Generates an EAN-13 barcode for a given material number."""

    combined_num = str(random_digits) + str(material_num)
    mybarcode = barcode.EAN13(combined_num, writer=ImageWriter())
    return (combined_num, mybarcode)

def save_barcode_and_data(material_num, part_desc, machine_type, output_dir, random_digits):
    """Generates a barcode, saves it as an image, and creates a dictionary with part information."""

    mybarcode = generate_barcode(material_num, random_digits)
    filename = f"{material_num} - {mybarcode}"

    # Save as PNG for wider compatibility
    mybarcode.save(f"{output_dir}/{filename}.png")

    data = {
        'M/C Type': machine_type,
        'mc_type_code': random_digits,
        'Material Code New': material_num,
        'Part Description': part_desc,
        'mat_code_type': mybarcode[0],
        'barcode_number': mybarcode[1]  # Store the barcode object for future use (optional)
    }
    return data

def create_and_save_excel(data_list, output_filename=f"Sparepart Barcodes - {date.today()}.xlsx"):
    """Creates a pandas DataFrame from a list of dictionaries and saves it to an Excel file."""

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
    df.to_excel(output_filename, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # examples of directory
    input_dir = "C:\\Users\\cxx\\Downloads\\Need to Create Barcode.xlsx"
    output_dir = "C:\\Users\\cxx\\Downloads\\miniprojects\\eng_barcode_scanner"

    # Read spare parts data from Excel (replace with your actual logic)
    sparepart_df = pd.read_excel(input_dir, sheet_name='Sheet1')

    barcodes = []
    for i in range(len(sparepart_df)):
        part_desc = sparepart_df['Part Description'][i]
        material_num = sparepart_df['Material Code New'][i]
        machine_type = sparepart_df['M/C Type'][i]

        random_digits = generate_random_n_digits(2)
        data = save_barcode_and_data(material_num, part_desc, machine_type, random_digits)
        barcodes.append(data)

    create_and_save_excel(barcodes)

    print("Barcodes generated and saved successfully!")

I'm facing error like this
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MuhaAufa1\Downloads\Stock Audit - Barcode Creation\main.py", line 64, in <module>
    data = save_barcode_and_data(material_num, part_desc, machine_type, random_digits)
TypeError: save_barcode_and_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'random_digits'

it should be generating barcode image and excel file

your function save_barcode_and_data takes 5 arguments but you only provided four, you missed the fourth: output_dir
